# searching a filename having number in it from command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt

I want to search zip files in directory based on pattern and have to list out in .txt file
e.g. I am having abc.zip and abc123.zip(123 can be any random numbers) 
My code

```
For %%F in [fullpath]\abc*.zip Do @Echo %%~ftF>> test.txt
```

(enclosed in batch file)
gives me output as

```
[modified date][fullpath]abc.zip
[modified date][fullpath]abc123.zip
```

Now the twist here is, I want to list out only 
    abc123.zip 
    and not 
    abc.zip
And I cannot give pattern like abc123*.zip, as 123 can be any random numbers and they are not fixed.
Thanks

Comment: @BobbyJack no, it's `cmd` (which is often wrongly called a "DOS-window")

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split the file name using numbers as delimiters, trying to get a second token. If it is not found, the `do` clause of the inner `for` will not be executed

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (abc*.zip) do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=0123456789" %%b in ("x%%~nxa") do @echo %%~fta
    )
```

**note**: Just in case the `abc*.zip` could be later replaced, there is a `x` (can be any non numeric character) included in the file name to process by the inner `for` loop. It is included to properly handle files with only numbers in the file name.

**edited** - As it seems only a specific file pattern should be matched, code changes slightly

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (customer*.zip) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=0123456789" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
            if /i "%%b"=="customer" if /i "%%c"==".zip" @echo %%~fta
        )
    )
```

That is, we still break the file name using the inner `for` to remove the numbers, but now we retrieve the two tokens and check if the first one is the searched name and the second one only the extension, the two elements that should remain if we remove all the numbers in the middle of a matching file.

Or, with less performance (subshell and pipe creation are slower that direct tokenization of the string) but easier to read

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /b /a-d customer*.zip 
        ^| findstr /r /x /i /c:"customer[0-9][0-9]*\.zip"
    ') do echo %%~fta
```

This uses a `dir` command to list the files and `findstr` to filer the list and only retrieve those that match the indicated pattern.

Comment: can we twist this again to separate files as abc123.zip and abcde123.zip? As if my first line is searching abcde*.zip then I will get result as abcde123.zip and if I am searching abc*.zip, I will get both filenames, but my intention is only to get abc123.zip and not abcde123.zip? The above logic checks only for numers in second part but what if both files having a number as both files are getting appended by date and timestamp, in this case above condition may get failed.

Comment: @user2409235, may be. What file should be processed? Are you interested *only* on `abc123.zip` (yes numbers can change) or are there other patterns to handle?

Comment: I am having customer010715013210.zip and customer_assign010715013210.zip filenames and I want to seperate these two. I cannot give customer*.zip, as it will list both files, it should not give second file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d abc*.zip ^|findstr /r [0-9]') do ( set file=%%i
      echo !file!
  )
)>test.txt
type test.txt | more
exit /b 0
```

Comment: You don't need the interim variable `file`, and therefore you also don't need delayed expansion...

Comment: @aschipfl you are right. Just in case of need to use substrring :)